# [ask]Visual Studio 2012 Error_System.ArgumentException_

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, argumentexception

what is this error?
I was writing a new program but I saw an error bur I don't know what is it!
!`http://rozup.ir/up/salardesigner/Pictures/eror.png`

Comment: Image links are intended for real *images*. You've taken a picture of *code*, which is much more easily included as *text*. Edit your question to put the code in directly, and also copy and paste the stack trace into the question, including the message from the exception.

Comment: the irony is the `[ask]` in the question title [ask]

Comment: When someone edits your question to improve it, don't edit it back!  Paste your code, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to replace `""` with `""` - this is illegal.

Remove `.Replace("", "");`